# Newbie: Unable to trace Free variable in expression error. Prolog Programming

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

Just started programming in Prolog. I wrote a couple of clauses.

```
predicates
parent(symbol,symbol)
male(symbol)
female(symbol)
mother(symbol,symbol)
father(symbol,symbol)
brother(symbol,symbol)
sister(symbol,symbol)
uncle(symbol,symbol)
clauses
parent(arthur,fred).
parent(arthur,george).
parent(arthur,bill).
parent(arthur,percy).
parent(arthur,ginny).
parent(arthur,ron).
parent(arthur,charlie).



parent(molly,fred).
parent(molly,george).
parent(molly,bill).
parent(molly,percy).
parent(molly,ginny).
parent(molly,ron).
parent(molly,charlie).
parent(rowling,arthur).
parent(rowling,james).


parent(james,harry).
parent(lily,harry).

female(molly).
female(ginny).
female(lily).
female(rowling).


male(X) if not(female(X)).


brother(X,Y) if male(Y),X<>Y,brother(Y,X).
brother(X,Y) if X<>Y,parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y),male(X).

mother(X,Y) if parent(X,Y),female(X).
father(X,Y) if parent(X,Y),male(X).
sister(X,Y) if parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y),female(X),X<>Y.
uncle(X,Y) if parent(Z,Y),brother(X,Z).
```

But when i am trying to ask question

```
brother(X,james)
```

It is showing Free variable in expression at **X**<>Y in line

```
brother(X,Y) if male(Y),X<>Y,brother(Y,X).
```

I am unable to trace what is the problem with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you could try to simplify the rule

```
brother(X,Y) if male(Y),X<>Y,parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y).
```

but this wouldn't work because male/2 it's defined only in negative terms.
To make it work I would add:

```
person(X) :- parent(X,_) ; parent(_,X).
male(X) :- person(X), not(female(X)).
```

Now male/1 is able to generate positive information...

(note: untested code)

**edit** a better way, without adding person/1, could be

```
/* Y is brother of X */
brother(X,Y) if parent(Z,X), parent(Z,Y), X<>Y, male(Y).
```

Comment: what i wnated to implement is if X is brother of Y and Y is male then Y is also brother of X. Anyway, i got this. The problem is with the definition of male. It is only declared in negative term.